# add dependency to .exe and execute with parameter from MSIX installer

Tags: msix, webview2, appinstaller

Hi I am trying to learn how to create an MSIX .appinstaller to distribute and automatically update an app on a local intranet.

I am trying to test the new WebView2. I need the installer to run the webview2 evergreen runtime .exe file in silent mode as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#:%7E:text=The%20WebView2%20Runtime%20allows%20apps,yet%20available%20in%20the%20browser.)

I am not sure how to do this and cant find anything from google. I have downloaded the file and added it to my package project. how can I add this to the installer so it runs before installation?

Comment: We don't have examples or solutions for this yet. However, it may be possible to run the WebView2 Runtime installer using powershell scripts in MSIX using the Package Support Framework (PSF):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/psf/run-scripts-with-package-support-framework

Comment: Thanks I looked into this and tried. For me I cant install the nuget package let alone get it working - Error NU1202 Package Microsoft.PackageSupportFramework 1.0.200410.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.PackageSupportFramework 1.0.200410.1 does not support any target frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to [use the PowerShell support from the Package Support Framework to trigger an MSI installation](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=41018). You can do the same for an EXE.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer*